# combining water pressure regulators to achieve a higher pressure

Tags: plumbing, water-pressure

Can I combine two or more pressure regulators to achieve a higher pressure than their rated value?

That is, in the following diagram would the output be 100 psi?

[image: diagram]

I assume that I would need check valves after the regulators as I won't have a precise alignment of each regulator.

Background:  I want to create a high pressure aeroponics system and ensure the pressure is consistent.  The pressure regulators I've found that work up to 100 PSI are (1) ridiculously expensive, (2) copper/brass which won't work with RO water, and (3) typically NPT fittings.  I'm using 3/8 push-to-connect (JG) fittings and have [found a regulator that works up to 50 PSI](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07S4K3B2S) so I *think* this might work but also worry I'm overlooking some basic physics/plumbing.  Or maybe there is a simpler/better part out there?

Comment: If this will also be for domestic use bear in mind that most domestic plumbing fixtures/appliances aren't designed to handle 100 psi. Your going to be blowing out fittings resulting in damage that could be serious. As long as that isn't an issue for you, why not forego the PRV and just let your 110 psi flow?

Comment: @HoneyDo Appreciated.  Most of the fittings are rated for 160 PSI but I will be sure to check each.  I wanted to keep the PSI constant to achieve a uniform droplet size.  As the expansion tank drains the pressure will drop (and the pump will turn back on) but I may just have to accept that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pressure at the regulated side will be 50psi.

Shunting several regulators can help regulate the pressure under high flow when there would be too much pressure drop through one regulator's orifice under flow. The multiple regulators will share the flow, but not double (or sum) the psi.

This arrangement aims to deal with a high "turn down ratio" (the ratio between high and low flow). In this case two regulators are parallel in the flow and their set points are slightly offset, so that the regulator with a smaller orifice opens at a high set point, and as flow increases and pressure drops, the larger regulator will open at a lower set point and help with the flow.

This is more than you asked for, but a bit of perspective is perhaps helpful, showing where parallel regulators are indeed used.